# autoincrement as primary key causing duplicate entries

Tags: php, mysql, primary-key, auto-increment

I want an id and name to be primary key for my table. I want to increment id with every insert, so i set it to auto_increment. The problem is when i insert into table a new entry with same name, it inserts it with a new id and there are duplicate entries with same name and different ids. I don't want to search the table beforehand to see if there is any entry beforehand. Please help me how to correct this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have done something like this

```
CREATE TABLE table1
   id unsigned integer autoincrement,
   name varchar,
   ....
   primary key (id,name)
```

This primary key does not select on unique name, because the autoincrement id will always make the **key as a whole** unique, even with duplicate `name`-fields.

Also note that long primary keys are a **bad** idea, the longer your PK, the slower inserts and selects will execute. This is esspecially bad on InnoDB, because the PK is included in each and every secondary key, ballooning your index files.

Change it to this

```
CREATE TABLE table1
   id unsigned integer autoincrement primary key,
   name varchar,
   ....
   unique index `name`(name)
```

Comment: thanks for the tip...  Did not knew about that.. Will take care of that too.. Thanks again..

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to be unique by name, you need to add a unique index on the name field, and then you can use the mysql syntax for on duplicate key: [mysql reference for on duplicate key](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could apply a unique index to your name field, or if you're storing people, allow duplicate names.

Answer (score 0):

Add UNIQUE(`your_column_name`) where you should replace `your_column_name` with the column in your database.

Comment: This will work, but the OP needs to also change the primary key definition if he wants his queries to not be slow.